# Install and load R packages from a packaged solution (Ubuntu)

Tags: r, devtools, rscript

I have the following DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: test
Title: Test Project
Version: 0.1
Author: 
    person("First", "Last", email = "first.last@test.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Maintainer: 
    First Last <first.last@test.com>
Description: This is a template project.
License: GPL
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Depends: 
    R (>= 3.5.0)
Imports:
    mongolite
Suggests: 
    testthat
```

I need to import `mongolite`. Thus, I previously installed it using `requirements.R`:

```
dir.create("library")

install.packages("testthat", lib="library")
install.packages("mongolite", lib="library")
```

Then I executed `requirements.R` as follows:

```
Rscript --verbose requirements.R
```

To load packages, I do:

```
Rscript --verbose -e "devtools::load_all()"
```

This is when I get the error:

```
Error: Dependency package(s) 'mongolite' not available.
<error/rlang_error>
Dependency package(s) 'mongolite' not available.
Backtrace:
    █
 1. └─devtools::load_all()
 2.   └─pkgload::load_all(...)
 3.     └─pkgload:::load_imports(path)
 4.       └─pkgload:::abort_for_missing_packages(res, imports$package)
In addition: Warning message:
In (function (dep_name, dep_ver = "*")  :
  Dependency package 'mongolite' not available.
Execution halted
```

What is wrong in my setup?

Comment: The Rscript doesn't know that you used a custom/non-standard library when installing the package. Maybe try `R_LIBS=./library Rscript --verbose -e "devtools::load_all()"`.

Comment: @MrFlick: Wow! Cool, this helped! What does it exactly do? Maybe I should set it in `requirements.R`?

Comment: By default R looks for packages at a certain location. You can run `.libPaths()` to see where that default place is. When you specify `library=` in `install.packages` you are overriding that default. R does not remember that change from session to session. By setting the `R_LIBS` environment variable, you are changing the default location where R looks for packages.